# Angular 2: radio buttons not working

Tags: angular

I intend these to be two radio buttons such that a user can select one or the other. But they are both showing on the form as already checked and cannot be unchecked.

```html
   

<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="radio" name="paymentType" id="paymentType" 
            [(ngModel)]="payment.paymentType"
            [value]="PayPal" required>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="radio" name="paymentType" id="paymentType" 
          [(ngModel)]="payment.paymentType" 
            [value]="Credit" required>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't use `checked`, rather make an option the selected one by assigning the value `'PayPal'` or `'Credit'` to `payment.paymentType` See also https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor There is no `checked` in the example.

Comment: Note that `name` attribute is defined twice and should probably be `paymentType` for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="radio" name="paymentType"
        [(ngModel)]="payment.paymentType"
        [value]="PayPal" required>
</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="radio" name="paymentType"
      [(ngModel)]="payment.paymentType"
      [value]="Credit" required>
</label>
</div>
```

Remove the extra name in both `radio` buttons and `[checked]` binding, then both will be unchecked at first. Radios with the same name are in a radio group, so when you check one `radio` button the other will be unchecked.

Comment: They're still checked without the name="paymentType"

Comment: did you remove `name=paymentType2` also? @koque

Comment: Didn't realize I had two name="".  I now have it exactly as you do, but now only the second one is checked and  I cannot check or uncheck either one of them.

Comment: @koque Günter's comment and link to documentation point at the key issue: remove the `checked` attribute, it conflicts with ngModel. https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor

Comment: I removed the [checked] attribute. The problem persists.

Comment: @koque edited to add a plunker. Could you update your question with current state if you've made edits but still have an issue?

Comment: @stealththeninja if you keep the `[checked]=false` it will still work in Plunker and any other editor

Comment: @koque check the answer, and run the snippet

Comment: @Peter Haddad Thanks, I see that it works. I have precisely what you have, for some reason it is not working for me.

Comment: I am using angular 2 and Visual Studio Code.